# R:How to create a boxplot with different types of data？

Tags: r

I am trying to get a picture like this:
[image]

In the picture, the parameters (a, b, and c of the triangle distribution  ), their distributions, and confidence intervals of the parameters are based on the original datasets, and simulated ones are generated by parametric and nonparametric bootstrap. How to draw a picture like this in R? Can you give a simple example like this? Thank you very much!

Here is my code.

```
x1<-c(1300,541,441,35,278,167,276,159,126,170,251.3,155.84,187.01,850)
x2<-c(694,901,25,500,42,2.2,7.86,50)
x3<-c(2800,66.5,420,260,50,370,17)
x4<-c(12,3.9,10,28,84,138,6.65)
y1<-log10(x1)
y2<-log10(x2)
y3<-log10(x3)
y4<-log10(x4)
#Part 1 (Input the data) In this part, I have calculated the parameters (a and b) and  the confidence interval (a and b ) by MLE and PB-MLE with different data sets(x1 to x4)
#To calculate the parameters (a and b) with data sets x1
y.n<-length(y1)
y.location<-mean(y1)
y.var<-(y.n-1)/y.n*var(y1)
y.scale<-sqrt(3*y.var)/pi
library(stats4)
ll.logis<-function(location=y.location,scale=y.scale){-sum(dlogis(y1,location,scale,log=TRUE))}
fit.mle<-mle(ll.logis,method="Nelder-Mead")
a1_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[1]
b1_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[2]
summary(a1_mle)# To calculate the parameters (a)
summary(b1_mle)# To calculate the parameters (b)
confint(fit.mle)#  To  calculate  the confidence interval (a and b ) by MLE
# load fitdistrplus package for using fitdist function
library(fitdistrplus)
# fit logistic distribution using MLE method
x1.logis <- fitdist(y1, "logis", method="mle")
A<- bootdist(x1.logis, bootmethod="param", niter=1001)
summary(A)      #  To calculate the parameters (a and b ) and the confidence interval (a and b ) by parametric bootstrap
a <- A$estim
a1<-c(a$location)
b1<-c(a$scale)

#To calculate the parameters (a and b) with data sets x2
y.n<-length(y2)
y.location<-mean(y2)
y.var<-(y.n-1)/y.n*var(y2)
y.scale<-sqrt(3*y.var)/pi
library(stats4)
ll.logis<-function(location=y.location,scale=y.scale){-sum(dlogis(y2,location,scale,log=TRUE))}
fit.mle<-mle(ll.logis,method="Nelder-Mead")
a2_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[1]
b2_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[2]
summary(a2_mle)# To calculate the parameters (a)
summary(b2_mle)# To calculate the parameters (b)
confint(fit.mle)#  To  calculate  the confidence interval (a and b ) by MLE
x2.logis <- fitdist(y2, "logis", method="mle")
B<- bootdist(x2.logis, bootmethod="param", niter=1001)
summary(B)
b <- B$estim
a2<-c(b$location)
b2<-c(b$scale)

#To calculate the parameters (a and b) with data sets x3
y.n<-length(y3)
y.location<-mean(y3)
y.var<-(y.n-1)/y.n*var(y3)
y.scale<-sqrt(3*y.var)/pi
library(stats4)
ll.logis<-function(location=y.location,scale=y.scale){-sum(dlogis(y3,location,scale,log=TRUE))}
fit.mle<-mle(ll.logis,method="Nelder-Mead")
a3_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[1]
b3_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[2]
summary(a3_mle)# To calculate the parameters (a)
summary(b3_mle)# To calculate the parameters (b)
confint(fit.mle)#  To  calculate  the confidence interval (a and b ) by MLE
x3.logis <- fitdist(y3, "logis", method="mle")
C <- bootdist(x3.logis, bootmethod="param", niter=1001)
summary(C)
c<- C$estim
a3<-c(c$location)
b3<-c(c$scale)

#To calculate the parameters (a and b) with data sets x4
y.n<-length(y4)
y.location<-mean(y4)
y.var<-(y.n-1)/y.n*var(y4)
y.scale<-sqrt(3*y.var)/pi
library(stats4)
ll.logis<-function(location=y.location,scale=y.scale){-sum(dlogis(y4,location,scale,log=TRUE))}
fit.mle<-mle(ll.logis,method="Nelder-Mead")
a4_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[1]
b4_mle<-coef(fit.mle)[2]
summary(a4_mle)# To calculate the parameters (a)
summary(b4_mle)# To calculate the parameters (b)
confint(fit.mle)#  To  calculate  the confidence interval (a and b ) by MLE
x4.logis <- fitdist(y4, "logis", method="mle")
D <- bootdist(x4.logis, bootmethod="param", niter=1001)
summary(D)
d <- D$estim
a4<-c(d$location)
b4<-c(d$scale)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make it easier for us to help you. It is also unclear what exactly your question is. Are you having trouble generating the numbers to plot, or do you have all the numbers and which to do the plot? If the latter, give us an example of your numbers are formatted. Show us what you've tried, and narrow down your specific question. The question as it is is too broad

Comment: Thank you for your generous comment.I think my problem is the latter. I add my code  ringht now. In this code, I have calculated the parameters (a and b )and the confidence interval by the original datasets and parametric bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## UPDATE

Here's my attempt. It's sloppy but I think it does what you want to do. It would be great if other people can provide a better solution or make suggestions/comments.

```
x1<-c(1300,541,441,35,278,167,276,159,126,170,251.3,155.84,187.01,850)
x2<-c(694,901,25,500,42,2.2,7.86,50)
x3<-c(2800,66.5,420,260,50,370,17)
x4<-c(12,3.9,10,28,84,138,6.65)
y1<-log10(x1)
y2<-log10(x2)
y3<-log10(x3)
y4<-log10(x4)

library(stats4)
library(fitdistrplus)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
```

First, put everything in a function so that you don't have to repeat yourself:

```
tmp <- function(y){
    y.n <-length(y)
    y.location <-mean(y)
    y.var<-(y.n-1)/y.n*var(y)
    y.scale<-sqrt(3*y.var)/pi
    ll.logis<-function(location, scale){-sum(dlogis(y, location, scale,log=TRUE))}

    fit.mle<-mle(ll.logis,
                 start = list(location = y.location, scale = y.scale),
                 method="Nelder-Mead")

    a_mle <-coef(fit.mle)[1] # mean a
    b_mle <-coef(fit.mle)[2] # mean b
    mle <- confint(fit.mle)

    mle_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c("a", "b"), c(a_mle, b_mle), mle))
    mle_df <- setNames(mle_df, c("par","mean", "lower", "upper"))
    mle_df$method <- "MLE"

    x.logis <- fitdist(y, "logis", method="mle")
    A <- bootdist(x.logis, bootmethod="param", niter=1001)
    a <- A$estim
    a_pbmle <-c(a$location)
    b_pbmle <-c(a$scale)

    pbmle_df <- data.frame(a_pbmle, b_pbmle)
    pbmle_df <- setNames(pbmle_df, c("a", "b"))
    pbmle_df$method <- "PB_MLE"

    return(list(MLE = mle_df,
                PBMLE = pbmle_df))
}
```

Then, using `lapply` you can apply function to `y1, y2, y3, y4` without writing down the same thing four times:

```
tmplist <- list(y1, y2, y3, y4)
tmplist2 <- lapply(tmplist, tmp)
```

This part is sloppy but this is all I could think of:

```
mL <- melt(tmplist2)
mL$par[is.na(mL$par)] <- mL$variable[is.na(mL$par)]
mL <- mL[,-6]
for(i in 2:4){
    mL[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(mL[,i]))
}

mL_a <- subset(mL, par == "a")
mL_b <- subset(mL, par == "b")
```

Then, you graph it with this:

```
g1 <- ggplot(mL_a) + geom_boxplot(aes(method, value)) +
    geom_point(aes(method, y = mean)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(method, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
    facet_grid(L1~.) +
    ylab("a") +
    coord_flip()

g2 <- g1 %+% mL_b +
    ylab("b")

g1.a <- g1 + theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())
g2.a <- g2 + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                   axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                   axis.title.y = element_blank())

grid.arrange(g1.a, g2.a, nrow = 1,
             widths = c(1.2, 1))
```

And you get

[image: result3]

## OLD ANSWER

Oh.. I started working on this before you posted the data so I worked with a fake example that I made up. Here's my code:

```
sL <- list()

for(i in c("FW&SW", "FW", "FW|S")){
    sL[[i]] <- rbind(data.frame(name = "MLE",
                          a = runif(10, -2, 0),
                          b = runif(10, 3, 5),
                          c = runif(10, -1, 2)),
    data.frame(name = "P-B MLE",
                          a = runif(10, -2, 0),
                          b = runif(10, 3, 5),
                          c = runif(10, -1, 2)),
    data.frame(name = "NP-B MLE",
                          a = runif(10, -2, 0),
                          b = runif(10, 3, 5),
                          c = runif(10, -1, 2)))
}
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

mL <- melt(sL)
mL$L1 <- factor(mL$L1, levels = c("FW|S", "FW", "FW&SW"))

g1 <- ggplot(subset(mL, variable == "a"), aes(name, value)) + geom_boxplot() +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(L1~.) + 
    theme(panel.margin=grid::unit(0,"lines"),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          plot.margin = unit(c(1,0.1,1,0), "cm"))

g2 <- g1 %+% subset(mL, variable == "b")
g3 <- g1 %+% subset(mL, variable == "c")

text1 <- textGrob("FW|S", gp=gpar(fontsize=12, fontface = "bold"))
text2 <- textGrob("FW", gp=gpar(fontsize=12))
text3 <- textGrob("FW&SW", gp=gpar(fontsize=12))



g1.a <- g1 + 
    ylab("a") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1.5, -1, -.5)) +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_blank())

g2.a <- g2 + ylab("b") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(3.5, 4, 4.5)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        strip.text.y = element_blank())
g3.a <- g3 + ylab("c") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-0.5, 0.5, 1.5)) +
    theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

grid.arrange(g1.a, g2.a, g3.a, nrow = 1,
             widths = c(1.5, 1, 1.1))
```

[image: result]

Let me try working with the data that you provided...

## EDIT (old edit with old data)

With the data you provided, I would just do this:

```
m <- confint(fit.mle)
MLE <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(a,b),m))
PBMLE <- as.data.frame(summary(b1)$CI)
sL <- list(MLE, PBMLE)
methods <- c("MLE", "P-B MLE")

myList <- lapply(1:2, function(i){
    x <- sL[[i]]
    colnames(x) <- c("Median", "low","high")
    x <- cbind(pars = c("a", "b"), method = methods[i], x)
})

df <- do.call("rbind", myList)

ggplot(df, aes(x = method, y = Median)) +
    geom_point(size = 4) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = high, ymin = low)) +
    facet_wrap(~pars, scale = "free") +
    xlab("") +
    ylab("")
```

[image: result 2]

which is a lot simpler than what I have above. You should look into `facet_wrap` and `grid_arrange`.

Comment: Thank you for your generous answer！Please forgive me to return to you  for a long time, I have changed your code for two days，but my plot is still very strange and I have been troubled by this problem for a long time. I try my best to deal it ,I changed the code which i provided before, and display the picture what i want to plot. This question is important for me,please help me to deal it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @J.Zhang I just added my attempt. Please take a look at it. I'll try to explain the code more if you have any questions.